# making auto-updating, facebook-style time formatting

Tags: javascript, templates, jquery-templates, mustache

Can some help me figure out why my javascript HTML template doesn't auto-update the time but the regular HTML does? Here's the templating library i'm using: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates

here's my JS (you can fiddle with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/SpYXM/76/ ):

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button', function(){
   var id= $(this).data('id');
   var data={id:id, string: "just now...", fxn: nicetime()};       
   var result = tmpl('<div id="string" data-id="'+id+'">{%=o.string%}</div><div id="function" data-id="'+id+'">{%=o.fxn%}</div>', data);     
   $('div[data-id="'+id+'"]').html(result);   
   nicetime();
});

function nicetime(){
  var time =  new Date(),
  var comment_date = setInterval(function() { 
  var time2 = time_since(time.getTime()/1000);
  $('#time_since').html(time2); 
  return time2; 
    }, 
  1000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button data-id="1">1</button>
<div data-id="1"></div>  //tmpl output
<div id="time_since"></div>  //non-tmpl output
```

Comment: Jquery data() function has nothing to do with data attributes, just use attr().

Comment: @Musa thanks, do you have a suggestion on setInterval problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYXM/89/).

With JavaScript templating, you generally want to template **once**, then update the values of specific elements dynamically, as opposed to resetting the innerHTML of an entire element every second.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button', function(){
    var id= $(this).val(),
        time = +new Date,
        data = {
            id: id,
            string: "just now..."
        },    
        result = tmpl('<span class="string">{%=o.string%}</span>', data),
        tgt = $('#'+id),
        str;
    tgt.html(result);    
    str = tgt.find('.string');
    window.setInterval(function() {
        str.html(time_since(time/1000));
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: awesome, let me investigate a little closer but think this will work!

Comment: ok, now I get it. keep the template values as strings and then just find and run the setInterval on those values after the template is laid down. thanks!